# Expect a function to throw an exception in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have a function (`hostelService.book`) that returns a promise: return `Promise.resolve(response);`
 and I made this test:

```
const action = async () => {
        await hostelService.book(id);
    };


  await expect(action).rejects.toThrow();
```

but I have this error:

```
 Matcher error: received value must be a promise
```

Comment: It's only `toThrow` that *calls* the supplied value. `rejects` requires it to *already* be a promise, not a function that returns one. I don't think `.rejects.toThrow()` makes sense at all; you probably want `expect(hostelService.book(id)).rejects.toEqual(someError)`. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#rejects.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Jest is throwing this error `Matcher error: received value must be a promise` because in  `expect` you are  just passing the function reference. Without  `()`  - `action`  is just a function reference it will not return anything.

To fix this issue you have to call the function in expect like `action()` so it will return the promise object.

And the second part, you have to throw error  like. `Promise.reject(new Error('some error'));` in the reject so the `tothrow` condition can be full filled.

**Example:**

```
function hostelService() {
   return Promise.reject(new Error('some error'));
}

const action = async () => {
   await hostelService();
};

it( "Should throw the error", async () => {
   await expect(action()).rejects.toThrow('some error');
});
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Your test fails because you're awaiting the promise (and therefore, it is no longer a Promise when you call `.rejects` on it). If you remove `await` from the last statement, it should do the trick:

```js
const action = async () => {
  await hostelService.book(id);
};

expect(action()).rejects.toThrow();
```

Here is some rationale behind it. `async` automatically wraps your return type into a Promise. However, when you call `await`, it synchronously "unwraps" the value of a given Promise and therefore it can't call `.rejects` on the result (unless you wrap a Promise into another Promise).

I've composed [a small example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-mdy7x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&previewwindow=tests&theme=dark) to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: I would say this is wrong. `await` has a lower precedence than `.`, so you will not await on .rejects, but await on .rejects.toThrow(). If you do not await, your test will succeed even if no error is thron in the action. The small example also seems flawed. It always passes, even if I add a expect(1).toBe(2)...

Comment: Thanks for the important note @mmey! My answer only addresses the question that has been asked: how to fix the "Matcher error: received value must be a promise" error. I totally agree that the answer that Sohail Ashraf gave is more comprehensive as it explains the situation you describe above, but it never was my intention to rewrite someone else's code along with that.

Comment: The `expect` needs to be awaited for it to able to fail the test. Fixing an error by introducing a logic mistake is not something I consider a valid answer.

Comment: This explanation helped me, my test was missing the .rejects

Comment: This answer is misleading! The `expect` should be awaited

Answer (score 8):

It seems you almost have it. I have created a codesandbox with a function that throws an error and a test that passes. You can run it with `npm run test` in a terminal inside codesandbox. Here's the link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-goodall-ssss4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

But basically the code is this:

```js
const action = async () => {
  throw new Error("error!")
}

describe("func", () => {
  it("should fail", async () => {
    await expect(action()).rejects.toThrow()
  })
})
```

The difference with the code you showed is the call in `action()` that was missing, maybe that was the type error. I don't know if that was a mistake or it wasn't just code and you just meant to explain what you wanted. In the future, for better understanding and to help your future "helpers", you should post a snippet of your code (or modified to avoid property issues).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't test rejects directly with `toThrow()`. Rejects it self is an error object so you can test for equality.

```js
test('', () => {
  // dont forget to call the action. 
  await expect(action()).rejects.toEqual(new Error())
});
```

You can find more workarounds here https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1700

Answer (score 1):

Here action is function and you're not calling it from expect. I've also removed await from last line

Try this solution

```
const action = async () => {
  await hostelService.book(id);
};
expect(action()).rejects.toThrow();
```

Comment: Your last comment is incorrect. You should not remove `await` from the `expect(...).rejects.toThrow('some message');` statement. It may or may not work depending on if it's the last statement of the test etc, but what you're essentially doing is finishing the test with async code still executing, which might mean you'd be calling tear down code mid-test. Always await asynchronous calls in your tests.