# jest cases failing inside describe

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write test cases for react native using Jest and I am encountering the following issues. I executed the function manually and its working as expected but in test cases its not.

**Home.js**

```
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Home extends Component {
  primeNumber = num => {
    let isPrime = false;
    if (num === undefined) {
      throw new Error('Please pass a input value');
    } else if (typeof num !== 'number') {
      throw new Error('The input value should be a integer only');
    } else if (num < 0) {
      throw 'Negative integers cannot be prime';
    } else if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
      throw new Error('O or 1 is neither prime not composite number');
    } else if (num > 1) {
      for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
          isPrime = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (isPrime) return 'Its a prime number';
      else return 'Its not a prime number';
    }
  };


   render() {
      return (
         <View> 
            <Text> Home </Text>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
```

**Home-test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './home';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe("'Prime Number", () => {
  let homeInstance = renderer.create(<Home />).getInstance();

  it('should throw an error if called without an argument', () => {
    expect(homeInstance.primeNumber).toThrow('Please pass a input value');
  });

  it('should throw an error if the input value is a string', () => {
    expect(homeInstance.primeNumber('Ahmed')).toThrow(
      'The input value should be a integer only',
    );
  });

  it('Negative number cannot be prime', () => {
    expect(homeInstance.primeNumber(-1)).toThrow(
      'Negative integers cannot be prime',
    );
  });

  it('0 is not a prime number', () => {
    expect(homeInstance.primeNumber(0)).toThrow(
      'O or 1 is neither prime not composite number',
    );
  });

  it('1 is not a prime number', () => {
    expect(homeInstance.primeNumber(1)).toThrow(
      'O or 1 is neither prime not composite number',
    );
  });

  it('Prime Number', () => {
    expect(homeInstance.primeNumber(2)).toEqual('Its a prime number');
  });

  it('Not a Prime Number', () => {
    expect(homeInstance.primeNumber(4)).toEqual('Its not a prime number');
  });
});
```

**Error log after executing the tests**

```
'Prime Number
    ✕ should throw an error if called without an argument (1 ms)
    ✕ should throw an error if the input value is a string
    ✕ Negative number cannot be prime
    ✕ 0 is not a prime number
    ✕ 1 is not a prime number
    ✕ Prime Number
    ✕ Prime Number

  ● 'Prime Number › should throw an error if called without an argument

    expect(received).toThrow(expected)

    Expected substring: "Please pass a input value"

    Received function did not throw

      36 |
      37 |   it('should throw an error if called without an argument', () => {
    > 38 |     expect(homeInstance.primeNumber).toThrow('Please pass a input value');
         |                                      ^
      39 |   });
      40 |
      41 |   it('should throw an error if the input value is a string', () => {

      at Object.toThrow (src/screens/Home/home.test.js:38:38)

  ● 'Prime Number › should throw an error if the input value is a string

    expect(received).toThrow(expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a function

    Received has value: undefined

      40 |
      41 |   it('should throw an error if the input value is a string', () => {
    > 42 |     expect(homeInstance.primeNumber('Ahmed')).toThrow(
         |                                               ^
      43 |       'The input value should be a integer only',
      44 |     );
      45 |   });

      at Object.toThrow (src/screens/Home/home.test.js:42:47)

  ● 'Prime Number › Negative number cannot be prime

    thrown: "Negative integers cannot be prime"

      45 |   });
      46 |
    > 47 |   it('Negative number cannot be prime', () => {
         |   ^
      48 |     expect(homeInstance.primeNumber(-1)).toThrow(
      49 |       'Negative integers cannot be prime',
      50 |     );

      at it (src/screens/Home/home.test.js:47:3)
      at Object.describe (src/screens/Home/home.test.js:34:1)

  ● 'Prime Number › 0 is not a prime number

    expect(received).toThrow(expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a function

    Received has value: undefined

      52 |
      53 |   it('0 is not a prime number', () => {
    > 54 |     expect(homeInstance.primeNumber(0)).toThrow(
         |                                         ^
      55 |       'O or 1 is neither prime not composite number',
      56 |     );
      57 |   });

      at Object.toThrow (src/screens/Home/home.test.js:54:41)

  ● 'Prime Number › 1 is not a prime number

    expect(received).toThrow(expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a function

    Received has value: undefined

      58 |
      59 |   it('1 is not a prime number', () => {
    > 60 |     expect(homeInstance.primeNumber(1)).toThrow(
         |                                         ^
      61 |       'O or 1 is neither prime not composite number',
      62 |     );
      63 |   });

      at Object.toThrow (src/screens/Home/home.test.js:60:41)

  ● 'Prime Number › Prime Number

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "Its a prime number"
    Received: undefined

      64 |
      65 |   it('Prime Number', () => {
    > 66 |     expect(homeInstance.primeNumber(2)).toEqual('Its a prime number');
         |                                         ^
      67 |   });
      68 |
      69 |   it('Prime Number', () => {

      at Object.toEqual (src/screens/Home/home.test.js:66:41)

  ● 'Prime Number › Prime Number

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "Its not a prime number"
    Received: undefined

      68 |
      69 |   it('Prime Number', () => {
    > 70 |     expect(homeInstance.primeNumber(4)).toEqual('Its not a prime number');
         |                                         ^
      71 |   });
      72 | });
      73 |

      at Object.toEqual (src/screens/Home/home.test.js:70:41)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       7 failed, 3 passed, 10 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.563 s, estimated 1 s
```

can someone please help me resolve this issue?

I am new to this and trying to figure but could not get a proper answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expect a function to throw an exception in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747420/expect-a-function-to-throw-an-exception-in-jest)

Answer (score 0):

See the API doc about [.toThrow(error?)](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror).

It should be:

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe("'Prime Number", () => {
  let homeInstance = renderer.create(<Home />).getInstance();

  it('should throw an error if called without an argument', () => {
    expect(() => homeInstance.primeNumber()).toThrow('Please pass a input value');
  });
})
```